# Throttling of Flow not working when created from Route

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Consider routes containing all the HTTP services

```
val routes:Route = ...
```

I wish to throttle number of requests so I used `Route.handleFlow(routes)` to create flow and called throttle method with finite duration.

Finally, I created HTTP binding using

```
Http().bindAndHandle(flowObjectAfterThrottling, hostname, port)
```

When HTTP requests are fired from a loop throttling is not obeyed by `akka`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the http requests being "fired from a loop" may be using separate connections.  Each incoming connection is throttling at the appropriate rate but the aggregate throughput is higher than expected.

**Use Configurations Instead**

You don't need to write software to set limiting rates for your `Route`.

If you are only concerned with consumption of a resource, such as disk or RAM, then you can remove the rate logic and use [akka configuration settings](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html) instead:

```
# The maximum number of concurrently accepted connections when using the
# `Http().bindAndHandle` methods.
max-connections = 1024

# The maximum number of requests that are accepted (and dispatched to
# the application) on one single connection before the first request
# has to be completed.
pipelining-limit = 16
```

This doesn't provide the ability to set a maximum frequency, but it does at least allow for the specification of a maximum concurrent usage which is usually sufficient for resource protection.